# In which class should I declare the schema for an SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating and SQLite Database in which to record barometer data. However, I do not quite know where to declare the schema for it. My tutorial does not mention creating a class for the database until after declaring the following:

```
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_sensor_data";
static final String COL_ID = "_id";
static final String COL_VALUE = "value";
static final String COL_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
private static final String DB_SCHEMA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_TIMESTAMP
        + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + COL_VALUE
        + " REAL " + ");";
```

I want to implement data storage when the app first runs and continue to record data each time the barometer changes (using a timestamp), could someone kindly inform me of a declaration I could use to ensure the recording starts and continues? Would I just have to declare in the onSensorChange() method or also in another method such as onStart()?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) tutorial. It will guide you step by step.

Youd should do insert() whenever you want to save the data, so calling it in onSensorChange() makes sense.

--------- Edit: entity declaration with default value for timestamp column

```
private static final String DB_SCHEMA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_TIMESTAMP
        + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " + COL_VALUE
        + " REAL " + ");";
```

Comment: Thank you, could you confirm whether I put COL_VALUE and COL_TIMESTAMP inside the insert() or just where values.put(String,Value) are?

Comment: IMHO the best way is to declare this column with timestamp as default value, like this:
" + COL_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ", then you don't have to set it's value in application code, because the database will do this by default.